# Unexpected MATLAB operator in very simple MatlabR2011b script

Tags: matlab

Very simple tutorial-script, that doesn't run on my MATLAB:

```
function y=test1(A)
[m,n]=size(A);
y = 0;
for i=1:m
    for j:n
        y=y+A(i,j);
    end
end
```

Saved in test1.m. When I call it with

```
A = [ 1 2; 3 4];
s = test1(A)
```

It gives me:

> Error: File: test1.m Line: 5 Column: 10
>   Unexpected MATLAB operator.

reffering to the n, which MATLAB also in line 5 points out as:

> Parse Error at ':': might be invalid MATLAB syntax.
>   In line two it also gives notice, that n might be unused..

How do I make sense of this, syntax looks correct to me?!

Comment: You must make your line 5 look more like your line 4, you need an `=`

Comment: I got that before, I just felt very bad for not seeing this myself in the first place.. grml Thanks again, I understood my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for `j:n` is bad syntax, you probably want `for j = 1:n`

Comment: I'm sorry if I annoyed anyone with this rather stupid mistake.. I'm a beginner and not good at proof-reading code, apperantly. :/

Answer (score 3):

It works when you edit line 5 to:
    for j=1:n